# how to give multiple array input without getting array ouf of bound exception

Tags: java, arrays

I have given 6 values in an array but I want it dynamically so that I won't get an array out of bound exception for as many inputs as I give. for example and I want the" PRINT" in the same line not in a line break.

Input from console

```
4
3.176 2
0.5 0.5
4 4
2 4
1 1.5 4 4 PRINT
```

the main class for taking input from the console:

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
        {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            int numpoints = 6;
     
            BoundingBox b = new BoundingBox(numpoints);
            double x[] = new double[6];
            int counter = 0;
            while(scanner.hasNext()){
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                if(line.equals("PRINT")){break;}
                //Inorder to use TEST WITH COUNT PLEASE UNCOMMENT IT .
                //if(line.equals("COUNT")){break;}
                String lineArr[]  = line.split(" ");
                Double xD = Double.valueOf(lineArr[0]);
                x[0] = (double)xD;
       
                if(counter == 0) {
                    x[1] = 0.0;
                    counter++;
                }else {
                Double yD = Double.valueOf(lineArr[1]);
                x[1] = (double)yD;
                }
                Double zD = 0.0;
                if(lineArr.length>=6){
                zD = Double.valueOf(lineArr[2]);
                x[2] = (double)zD;
                
                Double wD = 0.0;
                wD = Double.valueOf(lineArr[3]);
                x[3] = (double)wD;
                
                Double yD = 0.0;
                yD = Double.valueOf(lineArr[4]);
                x[4] = (double)yD;
                
                Double id=0.0;
                yD = Double.valueOf(lineArr[5]);
                x[5] = (double)id;
                
                
                
                
                
                
                }
                //System.out.println("xD, yD, zd,  wd)= "+xD+"+"+"+zD+"+" + wD+");
                 b.build(x);
                
            }
           
     
            System.out.println("\n ");
            b.putNew();
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in Java must be initialized with a fixed size at runtime. Once its size has been set, it cannot be changed.

If you want to store a list of items, you can use a `List`.

`List` is an interface, so you cannot call `new List();`, instead you must choose an implementation. `ArrayList` is a good all-round fit that, as the name suggests, is backed by an array.

For example:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
...
// continue indefinitely

System.out.println(list.get(0));  // prints the first thing in the list
```

will work fine.

Note that you must (not technically required but *very* good practice) specify the type of element in the `List` (i.e. `List<String>` or `List<Integer>`).

Comment: actually I want something that user can input as many input as they want and end with PRINT or COUNT so that  and get the result out ..as you can see my code above there is numpoints but I want to define in different way so that I won't array out of bound exception

Comment: Look into regular expressions. These can be used to determine whether a given input string is a number or not. Then, if you see a non-number, you can process it separately